# $f(x) = x$ $\forall \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that f is onto.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $f(x) = x$ $\forall \in \mathbb{Z}$ x. Prove that f is onto.

My current proof is that
both x,y belongs to R(Since f maps R to R), for each and every x there is same vaue of y (since f(n)=n that is x= y),so all values in y are definitely mapped by x values, so surjective.

Comment: I must admit that I don't understand your proof.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith how should I fix it or how would you prove then?

Comment: $f(x) = \mathbb R$? What are you trying to show? To show that $f$ is an onto, take an $y \in \mathbb R$ and show existence of a $x \in \mathbb R$ with $f(x) = y$. Why do you need $x$ and $y$ at the beginning of your proof?

Comment: Given $y \in \mathbb R$, find integers $n_1, n_2$ such that $n_1 < y < n_2$.  Use the intermediate value theorem on the interval $[n_1, n_2]$.

Comment: could you write your solution as a post?

Comment: What you have doesn't make sense.  You said let $x=n$, $f(x) = y$, and $x = y$.  But you just said let $x,y \in \mathbb R$.  So $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary.  So how can you say $x = y$?

Comment: Someone else wrote that solution.

Comment: Can you please clarify what it is that you want from the Math SE community?  Are you looking for a proof of the statement?  or are you asking for a critique of your argument?  If the latter, please add the [tag:solution-verification] tag to your question, and explain your desire for help in the question body itself.  If the former, please add some additional context---what theorems, definitions, or results are you expected to use?

Comment: I don't even understand what is $\forall \in \mathbb Z x$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson thank you for the feedback! edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$

Then $\exists n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$n\lt y \lt n+1$

Then $f(n)=n , f(n+1)=(n+1)$

By Intermediate Value Property of $f, \exists x \in (n,n+1)$ such that $f(x)=y$

So $f$ is onto